# parsing an irregular csv file with two delimiters in bash

Tags: bash, parsing, csv, awk, delimiter

All,

I am looking to parse a csv file with the following line

```
00000000-0000-0265-2510-017132647704,5690OD64_0W24zjsK-5GLmwjntrVyLDZhrmS,1,11/1/2014 7:29:02 AM,23435830,11179745,868,360655,69844,64637,43755,,,122.111.9.107,36,28389,-1,11677,3166,,0,11,,Apple iPad,,-1,-1,MM_CLD_Standard_Agency_43755_Daily_141101_00.csv
```

I am required to parse the file using two delimiters

```
"," & "_"
```

with the underscore occurring at the second and final columns. Currently I am using awk to parse the file as below but as you notice the occurrence of the underscore in col2 is causing the file to be parsed undesirably. I would like to know how to escape the underscore in col2 so that the string I am pulling out from the final column is not affected

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {$23="";print $4,$3,$2,$6,FILENAME}' $i|tail -n +2|awk -F ",|_" 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$10}'
```

The desired output would be as

```
11/1/2014 7:29:02 AM,1,5690OD64_0W24zjsK-5GLmwjntrVyLDZhrmS,11179745,141101
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Don't split on both via `FS`. Split on `,` via `FS` and manually use `split` on the two fields that need that too.

Comment: How comes the time `7:29:54` ?

Comment: @EtanReisner, would you please able to quote an example.

Comment: there isn't a strings like this `11179746,141101` in your input.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, sorry I have been mucking up describing the output. The value is 11179745 and 141101 is present in the filename which is the final column of the input file

Comment: Try again and keep it simple. You don't need a line with 30 fields (or whatever that is) to describe your problem, and a single line won't adequately demonstrate the problem. Just post say 3 or 4 lines of sample input, each with 4 or 5 fields that DEMONSTRATE your problem and the associated expected output from THAT input. The easier you make it for us to help you, the more likely we are to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{n=split($NF, a, /_/); print $4, $3, $2, $6, a[n-1]}' <<END
x,5690OD64_0W24zjsK-5GLmwjntrVyLDZhrmS,1,11/1/2014 7:29:02 AM,y,11179745,z,...,MM_CLD_Standard_Agency_43755_Daily_141101_00.csv
END
```

```
11/1/2014 7:29:02 AM,1,5690OD64_0W24zjsK-5GLmwjntrVyLDZhrmS,11179745,141101
```